# Redirect program output to my program

Tags: c, linux, posix, stdio

My program launches a helper program using fork() / execvp() and I'd like to show the helper program's output in my program's GUI. The helper's output should be shown line by line in a listview widget embedded in my program's GUI. Of course, I could just redirect the output to a file, wait until the helper has finished, and then read the whole file and show it. But that's not an optimal solution. Ideally, I'd like to show the helper's output as it is sent to stdout, i.e. line by line, while the helper is still working.

What is the suggested way of doing this?

From the top of my head, what comes to mind is the following solution but I'm not sure whether it will work at all because one process will write to the file while the other is trying to read from it:

1) Start the helper like this using execvp() after a fork():

```
./helper > tmpfile
```

2) After that, my program tries to open "tmpfile" using open() and then uses select() to wait until there's something to read from that file. Once my program has obtained a line of output, it sends it to my GUI's listview widget.

Is this how it should be done or am I totally on the wrong track here?

Thanks!

Comment: How about using pipes? Then your program can simply read from `stdin` (and yes you can still use `select`). So `./helper | your_program` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of that one... probably the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should open a `pipe` and monitor the progress of the child process using `select`. You can also use `popen` if you only need a one way communication, in that case you will get the file descriptor by a call to `fileno` on the returned `FILE*`.

See:

- [pipe](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pipe.html)
- [popen](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html)
- [select](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/select.html)
- [fileno](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fileno.html)

Comment: Thanks, popen() seems exactly what I was looking for. Just out of curiosity: How would I implement this with pipe() instead popen()? How do I start the helper program then?

Comment: @Andreas For the pipe way of doing things you can find a tutorial there: http://www.microhowto.info/howto/capture_the_output_of_a_child_process_in_c.html  but apparently the author was not aware of the `fileno` function.

Comment: Another question: The example of the popen() manual at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/popen.html doesn't use select() at all but simply polls the individual lines by looping over fgets(). Is this an acceptable way of doing this? Can I be sure that fgets() won't return NULL before the program terminates?

Comment: And another one: Is there any way to workaround the flushing problem? I need the helper program to flush buffers on every newline but it doesn't do so now because stdout is redirected to a pipe. I guess it's not legal to call setvbuf() on the FILE* returned by popen() to change the buffering mode to _IOLBF, is it?